# Suspend issues on AMD Ryzen 7 4800u with radeon graphics

Tags: suspend

I have quite an unusual problem with the suspend function on my Odin PC with AMD Ryzen 7 4800u (Lenovo IdeaCentre 3 All-in-One 24").

If I leave it to go to suspend after the amount of time set in Switchboard, everything works as it should.

If I want to manually suspend my PC from the Power menu, the following happens:

- cca 40% of the time everything works as it should
- cca 30% of the time the screen goes off but the PC is still running and I can bring it back to the login screen pressing several times the ESC key
- cca 30% of the time the screen goes off, the PC is still running but everything is frozen and I can only turn it off with the computer's power button.

Apart from this issue, I'm very happy with the Ryzen 7 performance and everything just works out of the box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Is there anything written to the `/var/log/syslog` file around the time when you are unable to wake the machine from suspend? 

Comment: This has been happening on the same computer from the public beta stage and back then I couldn't find anything. It may be a good idea to take a look now, with the stable release. Cheers.